# OpenGL: can I mix glBindBuffer with glBindBufferARB?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, buffer

Is glBindBuffer equivelent to glBindBufferARB ?

Are the enums (like GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB) equivilent? Can I use non-_ARB enum in glBindBufferARB?

Can I mix + match glBindBuffer() calls with glBindBufferARB()?

ALSO: if a card supports the _ARB extension, does it always support the core GL function - even if its OpenGL version isn't up to date??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is not legal to do that kind of thing, because core functionality and extensions are not exchangeable, even if they have the same name (one notable example is primitive restart).

However, in this particular case, they happen to be exactly the same with the exact same constants, so... although it's not legal, it is "ok" to use them interchangeably (i.e. nobody will notice if you don't tell them).

You cannot in general assume that if an ARB extension is present that the core funciton will be present as well. There exist many ARB extensions that are there solely to allow OpenGL implementations which cannot implement a full version for some reason to nevertheless provide at least *some* functionality that the hardware can provide.